# Accordion + toggle menu

Tags: jquery, menu, toggle, accordion

I have jquery menu with accordion and toggle effect. But it works with bugs: sometimes it closes all elements.

Can you help to do it best?

HTML:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Level 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">11</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">12</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
     <li>
        <a href="#">Level 2</a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li><a href="#">21</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">22</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li> 
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var sel = '#accordion'
$(sel + ' li a').toggle(
        function() {
            var checkElement = $(this).next();
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                return false;
            }
            if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
                $(sel + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal').removeClass('selected');
                checkElement.addClass('selected').slideDown('normal', function() {

                });
                return false;
            }
        },
        function() {
            $(sel + ' ul:visible').removeClass('selected').slideUp('normal', function() {

            });
        }
    );​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/uG6zB/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i looked over your code and I am not sure toggle is the best function for what you are trying to do, as I understand it.

I changed `toggle` to `click` and I changed your logic just a little.

the javascript looks like this now:

```
var sel = '#accordion'
$(sel + ' li a').click( function(){
    var checkElement = $(this).next();
    if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        checkElement.slideUp('normal').removeClass('selected');
    }
    else if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
        $(sel + ' ul:visible').slideUp('normal').removeClass('selected');
        checkElement.addClass('selected').slideDown('normal', function() {

        });
    }
});
```

With this javascript I was able to get the menus to go up and down with no quirky behavior.
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kJMAr/1/)